# Setting document location href prevents setting cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cookies

I want to record the current page in a cookie when user clicks on some link to provide a 'return to' link in the following page. by the way I don't use the page `Request.UrlReferrer` in asp.net as user might go through pagination in the in new page opened but the referral url must not change. here is my code:

```
$('.options a').click(function (e) {
    var a = $(this); 
    $.cookie('return-to', a.attr('href') + '#' + a.closest('.names').attr('id'), {expires:1});
   e.preventDefault();
   document.location.href = a.attr('href');
 });
```

The above code doesn't set the cookie but this one does:

```
$('.options a').click(function (e) {
        var a = $(this); 
        $.cookie('return-to', a.attr('href') + '#' + a.closest('.names').attr('id'), {expires:1});
       e.preventDefault();
     //  document.location.href = a.attr('href');
     });
```

why setting `document.location.href` is preventing setting the cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding path to the cookie options solved the problem. but I still don't get it as the domain doesn't change in the new page

```
$('.options a').click(function (e) {
    var a = $(this); 
    $.cookie('return-to', a.attr('href') + '#' + a.closest('.names').attr('id'), {expires:1, path:'/'});
   e.preventDefault();
   document.location.href = a.attr('href');
 });
```